# how to create google analytics ecommerce tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

I need your help with creating google analytics ecommerce tracking code for my website, the url is www DOT sunmountaingolf DOT co DOT uk.

can anyone create a code for me?

where should I paste that code? on the checkout page?

Any kinda help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is here: https://support.google.com/analytics/?hl=en#topic=3544906

Comment: I am unable to understand all that :( can you help with creating the code?

Comment: Take a look at some videos ... http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google+analytics+setup+tutorial+2013&sm=3

Comment: analytics and goals are already setup, i need help with ecommerce tracking code and pasting on my website.

Comment: <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46143915-1', 'sunmountaingolf.co.uk');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

is this correct???